# cambiar iconos segun canción que este sonando con jquery

Tags: jquery, html5

Tengo una lista de canciones. cada una con un icono para reproducir, quiero que cuando se pulse en una canción el icono cambie (icono pausa) y que cuando se pulse en otra canción la anterior su icono cambie. pero también cuando pulse en una canción y pulse en la misma canción el icono también cambie, es decir que solo halla un icono de pausa en la canción que este sonando.

```
<li class="lireproductor">
  <img id="idplay1"  class="play"  data-audio="1" data-img="1" src="images/play.png">Cuando amanece
</li>
<li class="lireproductor">
  <img id="idplay2"  class="play"  data-audio="2" data-img="2" src="images/play.png">animal
</li>
<li class="lireproductor"> 
  <img id="idplay3"  class="play"  data-audio="3" data-img="3" src="images/play.png">animal
</li>

document.addEventListener('play', function(d)
{

    //poner en play.png tdoas las canciones menos la que dispare la funcion
   // var iconos = document.getElementsByTagName('idplay');
    icono = $('#idplay' + $(this).data('img'));

    icono.attr('src','images/pause.png');
    for(var i = 0, len = icono.length; i < len;i++)
    {
        if(icono[i] != d.target)
        {

            icono[i].attr('src','images/play.png');

        }
    }
}, true);
```

www.jamondemono.com/mono en la seccion discografía en el disco la desvirtualización de las ideas tengo el reproductor.

me funciona lo que quiero pero si pulso en una canción, el icono cambia a pausa y luego pulso en otra canción  el icono de la anterior vuelve a play pero si pulsas dos veces sobre la misma cancion no se cambia el icono. (este es el problema)

he conseguido el cambio de icono con este código:

```
function iconopause1()
{

$("#idplay1").attr('src','images/pause.png');
$("#idplay2").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay3").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay4").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay5").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay6").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay7").attr('src','images/play.png');

}
```

pero es repetir mucho código y no me soluciona bien el problema.

Comment: Es un excelente proyecto Rafael, ¿tienes algún problema al implementarlo? ¿Podrías describirlo? Si no has hecho nada para lograr tu objetivo, el código que publicas no está relacionado con lo que quieres lograr. Sigue [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que incluyas el código que muestre __qué estás haciendo actualmente para solucionar tu problema__.

Comment: Bueno, me perdí un momento leyendo, que cuando pausas que cuando no, podías hacer una especies de interfaces así sean en paint, y las enumeras para tener la idea mas clara.

Comment: he editado mi pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un método rápido cambiando un poco el código que ya tienes. Dices que esto te funciona bien pero el problema es que se repite mucho código:

he conseguido el cambio de icono con este código:

```
function iconopause1()
{

$("#idplay1").attr('src','images/pause.png');
$("#idplay2").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay3").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay4").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay5").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay6").attr('src','images/play.png');
$("#idplay7").attr('src','images/play.png');

}
```

Una posible solución sería hacer esa función más genérica. Todos los iconos tienen la clase `play` y luego los ids son consecutivos. Así que podrías crear una función genérica a la que le pasas el id que quieres y que haga que todos los iconos con clase `play` vuelvan a tener el icono de play y sólo el de la id pasada tenga el de pausa. Algo así:

```
function iconopause(id)
{
    $(".play").attr('src','images/play.png');
    $("#idplay" + id).attr('src','images/pause.png');
}
```

Que podrías simplificar un poco más teniendo en cuenta que tienen un atributo `data-audio` que coincide con el id, y aún más poniéndo el código en un controlador del evento click en lugar de como una función independiente. Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando (no tenía iconos play/pause a mano, así que he usado rojo/verde en su lugar):

```js
$(".play").on("click", function() {
  $(".play").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff");
  $(this).attr("src", "http://placehold.it/40/0f0/fff");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="lireproductor">
    <img id="idplay1"  class="play"  data-audio="1" data-img="1" src="http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff">Cuando amanece
  </li>
  <li class="lireproductor">
    <img id="idplay2"  class="play"  data-audio="2" data-img="2" src="http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff">animal
  </li>
  <li class="lireproductor"> 
    <img id="idplay3"  class="play"  data-audio="3" data-img="3" src="http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff">animal
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Ahora queda el problema de que cambie el icono cuando se pulsa dos veces. Una posible solución sería comprobar la fuente de la imagen y si tiene la palabra "pause" cambiarlo. Pero te recomendaría una solución un poco más elegante que sería agregarle una clase al icono activo y comprobar si tiene o no esa clase (porque puede que cambies la imagen en el futuro, como con mis iconos rojo y verde y entonces te deje de funcionar).

La idea sería hacer algo así (extendiendo el código de arriba):

```
$(".play").on("click", function() {

  // cambiamos todos los iconos a play (rojo)
  $(".play").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff");

  // si el icono pulsado tiene la clase pause
  if ($(this).hasClass("pause")) {
    // le quitamos la clase
    $(this).removeClass("pause");
  } else {
    // si no, le quitamos la clase pause a todos
    $(".play").removeClass("pause");
    // se la añadimos al icono pulsado
    $(this).addClass("pause");
    // cambiamos el icono pulsado a pause (verde)
    $(this).attr("src", "http://placehold.it/40/0f0/fff");
  }

});
```

Y aquí te dejo un ejemplo ejecutable:

```js
$(".play").on("click", function() {

  $(".play").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff");
  
  if ($(this).hasClass("pause")) {
    $(this).removeClass("pause");
  } else {
    $(".play").removeClass("pause");
    $(this).addClass("pause");
    $(this).attr("src", "http://placehold.it/40/0f0/fff");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="lireproductor">
    <img id="idplay1"  class="play"  data-audio="1" data-img="1" src="http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff">Cuando amanece
  </li>
  <li class="lireproductor">
    <img id="idplay2"  class="play"  data-audio="2" data-img="2" src="http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff">animal
  </li>
  <li class="lireproductor"> 
    <img id="idplay3"  class="play"  data-audio="3" data-img="3" src="http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff">animal
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Alvaro no me funciona tu código, la función: $(".play").on("click", function() {

  $(".play").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/40/f00/fff");
  
  if ($(this).hasClass("pause")) {
    $(this).removeClass("pause");
  } else {...... no se ejecuta le he puesto un alert("prueba"); y no me muestra el alert

Comment: @RafaelHernández ¿Dónde colocas el código?

Comment: en un archivo .js al final de este

Comment: ¿Y las imágenes tienen la clase `play`?

Comment: <img id="idplay1"  onclick="iconopause(id)" class="play"  data-audio="1" data-img="1" src="images/play.png"> ademas le he puesto un alert a la funcion y no se ejecuta el alert

Comment: ¿Puedo ver el código que tienes en algún sitio? Es raro, porque parece que debería funcionar como funciona arriba. Quizás haya algún conflicto o algo

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UxxinBaP

Comment: @RafaelHernández No puedo verlo ahora mismo porque pastebin esta bloqueado en donde estoy. Luego le echo un ojo. Por curiosidad, ¿los botones se crean de manera dinámica? Si sí, cambia a `$("body").on("click", ".play", function() { ... }` para ver si funciona

Comment: ni con $("body").... funciona.  también tengo problemas con otra funcion jquery para poner unos estilos css al menu de bootstrap y no consigo darselos por que tampoco funciona....

Comment: tengo al principio del script un codigo que me pasaron, en el que se indica que no se puede usar this (usar el método call) será esto lo que esta provocando los errores? function ie_crearEvento(elemento, evento, mifuncion)
 {
  var fx = function()
  {

   mifuncion.call(elemento); //al no poder usar this, uso el método call
  };
  elemento.attachEvent('on' + evento, fx);
 }

Comment: era el código que mencionaba antes (el que usa el método call) , ya me funcionan los cambios de iconos correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr lo mismo usando clases CSS, por ejemplo:

```js
var $playlist = $('.playlist');
$playlist.on('click', 'i.fa', function(evt) {
var $currentSong = $(evt.currentTarget);
  
  $playlist.find('.fa-pause').toggleClass('fa-play fa-pause');
  $currentSong.toggleClass('fa-play fa-pause');
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<ul class="playlist">
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Cancion 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Cancion 2
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Cancion 3
  </li>
</ul>
```